# Is there anyway to modify one file and sync to the lower directory in OverlayFs?

Tags: linux, sshfs, overlayfs

I know about the 
overlayfs
that it treats lower directory as a read-only and copy_up when we want to modify the lower file

so is there any way to modify the lower file and it can copy the modified file to the lower directory?

> From
>   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt
>
> Changes to the underlying filesystems while part of a mounted overlay
>   filesystem are not allowed.  If the underlying filesystem is changed,
>   the behavior of the overlay is undefined, though it will not result in
>   a crash or deadlock.

Comment: It's impoosible cuz that's the rule of overlayfs. So I use mergerfs to do my own filesystem. 
Google mergerfs.

Comment: I've posted a couple of answers to my own question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393930) which covers this topic.